# How to update all elements of a nested map in elixir

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I'm trying to implement in Elixir some of the maze generation algorithms from the excellent book [Mazes for Programmers](https://www.amazon.fr/Mazes-Programmers-Twisty-Little-Passages-ebook/dp/B013HA1UY4/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=C7B2X5L9GF5R&keywords=Mazes%20for%20Programmers&qid=1667298331&qu=eyJxc2MiOiIwLjU2IiwicXNhIjoiMC44MSIsInFzcCI6IjEuMDAifQ%3D%3D&sprefix=mazes%20for%20programmers%2Caps%2C342&sr=8-1) by Jamis Buck. In imperative languages like Go or V it's a piece of cake but with Elixir I'm stuck.

A maze is a grid of cells. A cell holds information about in which direction we can move. It is represented as a `struct` with boolean members (`north: true` or `east: false`, etc.). A grid is a map where keys are tuples `{col, row}` and values are `Cell`s. If `mz` is a maze, `mz.grid[{0, 0}]` is the cell located at the upper left corner.

One of the basic operation is to open a path from one cell `c1` to another `c2` and most of the time, if we can go from `c1` to `c2`, we can also go from `c2` to `c1` which means this operation modifies both cells. To implement this, I have a function `open_to(maze, x, y, direction)` which returns a tuple of two cells `c1_new` and `c2_new` where the direction information in each cell had been changed. Then I can update the grid with `Enum.put(maze.grid, {x, y}, c1_new)`. Same for `c2_new`.

One of the most simple algorithm, the *binary tree* algorithm, needs to visit all cells one by one and open a bidirectional link with one of the neighbors. *Bidirectional* means that both cells need to be updated and the second cell may be visited only later. I'm stuck at this step as I can't find how to update the grid with the cells returned by `open_to()`. My Elixir pseudo code is as follows:

```
def generate(mz) do
  Enum.map(mz.grid, fn({{x, y}, c1}) ->
    neighbors = [Grid.cell_to(mz, x, y, :north), Grid.cell_to(mz, x, y, :east)]
    c2_dir = select_the_neighbor(neighbors)     # returns one of :north, :east or nil

    # Here! open_to returns the updated cells but what to do with them?
    {c1_new, c2_new} = if c2_dir != nil, do: Grid.open_to(mz, x, y, c2_dir)
  end)
end
```

I believe the issue comes from the data structure I've chosen and from the way I go through it, but I can't find another way. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question it's "how can each step in `Enum.map/2` update the maze and have that visible to each other and the final result?".

Where data structures in Elixir are immutable, you don't change the data another variable points to.

As a simple example, putting a key/value pair into a map creates an entirely new map:

```rb
iex(1)> map = %{a: 3}
%{a: 3}
iex(2)> Map.put(map, :a, 4)
%{a: 4}
iex(3)> map
%{a: 3}
```

In a similar fashion, `Enum.map/2` isn't intended for modifying anything except the value currently being operated on (and even then only in the new list, not the original). If you want to update some value based on each cell you may be looking for [Enum.reduce/3](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#reduce/3). It enumerates things like `Enum.map/2`, but it takes a value or "accumulator". The reducer function you pass in is called with an item and the accumulator and ought to return the updated value of the accumulator. Then the final value of that accumulator is what is returned from `Enum.reduce/3`.

So your pseudo code might look something like this:

```rb
def generate(mz) do
  # don't use the c1 from enumerating the grid--it could be out of date
  # you could also just enumerate the grid coordinates:
  #   - for x <- 0..width-1, y <- 0..height-1, do: {x, y}
  #   - Map.keys(mz.grid)
  Enum.reduce(mz.grid, mz, fn {{x, y}, _dont_use_this_c1}, mz ->
    neighbors = [Grid.cell_to(mz, x, y, :north), Grid.cell_to(mz, x, y, :east)]

    if c2_dir = select_the_neighbor(neighbors) do
      {c1_new, c2_new} = Grid.open_to(mz, x, y, c2_dir)
      mz
      |> Map.put({x, y}, c1_new)
      |> Map.put(find_x_y(x, y, c2_dir), c2_new)
    else
      # you have to return a maze, or other iterations will try adding cells to nil
      mz
    end
  end)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Brett. I didn't think about initializing the accumulator with the whole structure and then just update it... Clever. Just two details for the potential future readers: 1/ the accumulator is to be given as the second argument to the lambda in `reduce` and 2/ it's the accumulator that needs to be returned, not `mz`. Thanks for the help